# Why is my VS Code breakpoint (php) only working in one folder and not in others?

Tags: xdebug, breakpoints, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to debug a php file. I have installed the PHP Debug extension and configured PHP to debug using XDebug. Server is Apache (using Xampp).

The file I want to debug is in .../htdocs/Nuurd and breakpoints are hit. But when I open another folder and try to debug a file in (for instance) .../htdocs/Test it cannot be debugged, i.e. the program is finished without stopping at any breakpoint (it runs through).

Why does it depend on the folder and what settings are required to make xdebug work on any folder?

Answer (score 0):

The folder .vscode with launch.json was missing.

I copied it from another folder and that solved the problem (hopefully forever).